# BETWEEN using negative values and unsigned ints

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a typical **unsigned** int primary key `id`

```
select * from log_data where id between -129 and -120
```

seemingly tries to return every row in the table (or at least gets stuck at 'sending data' for hours)

```
id  select_type table      type     possible_keys   key     key_len   ref   rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      log_data    ALL     PRIMARY         NULL    NULL      NULL  357114  Using where
```

According to the docs on `BETWEEN` at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between: 
*This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type*

However,

```
select * from log_data where -129 <= id and id <= -120
```

behaves as I'd expect.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len  ref    rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      NULL    NULL    NULL            NULL    NULL     NULL   NULL    Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables
```

Is this a bug, or can this behavior be explained?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I can't think of any reason for it.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? Tried your code on 5.6.25 and it's ok (works as expected - no results in 0.001 seconds)

Comment: I'm on 5.6.19. If the query completed I'm not sure I'd actually get any rows but the table is >10gb and the query sits at "Sending data" for at least an hour. Were you trying it on a large table too?

Comment: Tested it on a 300k rows Table, some interesting observations but no explanation for your problem: PK signed -> PK is used in explain, rows:1, 0.0001s, PK unsigned -> not used id explain, rows:8, 0.08s

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM `log_data` WHERE `id` <= -129  and `id` >= -120